# Force an asp:LoginView to show the anonymous template with code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, vs-web-application-project

I have a loginView with a buttons button to allow an anonymous user to log in and when the user is logged in a logout button will be displayed. When the user clicks the logout button the user should be logged out and the anonymous template should be displayed.

I can log the user out but the loginView continues to display the authenticated template. How do I get it to show the anonymous template?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="user-login">Guest</asp:Label>
        <button id="guestSignIn" type="button" class="btn-user bg-anonymous" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Home-icon.png" Height="35" PostBackUrl="~/Profile.aspx" />
        <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" CssClass="user-login" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnLogOff" Text="Log out" CssClass="btn-user bg-user" runat="server" OnClick="LogOff" PostBackUrl="~/AboutMe.aspx" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="User">
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Home-icon.png" Height="20" CssClass=" mr-2" PostBackUrl="~/ProfilePage.aspx" />
                <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName2" runat="server" CssClass="user-login" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnLogOff1" Text="Log out" CssClass="btn-user bg-admin" runat="server" OnClick="BtnLogOff_Click" PostBackUrl="~/AboutMe.aspx" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>

protected void LogOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();

        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        Roles.DeleteCookie();

        try
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Expires = -1000;
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            //Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of or find.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you calling your LogOff method? You are probably doing a partial postback, so that the viewstate is keeping the template up. you have to specifically un-render it.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I got lazy when naming the button click event (LogOff). Just got frustrated with what I thought would be fairly easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The hint was in the solution I copied and pasted from another forum. The commented line of code:

```
//Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
```

DaniDev said that I was only getting a partial postback. This was because I set the postback URL on the button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Home-icon.png" Height="20" CssClass=" mr-2" PostBackUrl="~/ProfilePage.aspx" />
```

If I remove the PostBackUrl from the ImageButton tag and use the Response.Redirect method I get a complete postback and when the page reloads the LoginView reverts back to the anonymous template.

Thanx for the help DaniDev wherever you are!!

Comment: You are welcome. There should be a way to access the LoginView control in your method and have it display the correct template.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `Validate()` on the page after you clear out the session data?